# Powershell Microsoft Teams: Unexpected Behavior with Add-TeamChannelUser foreach loop

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a simple Powershell script to create a Microsoft Team, Channels, Users, and then to associate the Users with the Channels.  Everything works great with creating the new Team, creating new Channels, creating Team Users (both Owners and Members), but when I attempt to assign Users to Channels, the member's "Role" is ignored, and they are automatically added as Members.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
$NewTeamName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of new Team'
$NewTeam = New-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName
$GroupId = $NewTeam.GroupId
Import-csv createTeamChannels.csv | foreach{New-TeamChannel -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $_.cname -MembershipType Private}
Import-csv createTeamUsers.csv | foreach{Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupId -User $_.cuser -Role $_.crole}
Import-csv addChannelUsers.csv | foreach{Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $_.cdisplayname -User $_.cuser -Role $_.crole}
```

If, after running the script above, I run the following line on its own, using the data in the csv file, the User is assigned the appropriate Role.

```
Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $_.cdisplayname -User $_.cuser -Role $_.crole
```

Comment: It seems like you have to do two `Add-TeamChannelUser` steps. The first one adds them as a member. Then you need another one to add as an owner. I guess you cannot add them to the list as an owner without already being a member? Reading [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/add-teamchanneluser?view=teams-ps) it seems like that is by design and who knows why.

Comment: This worked, thank you (again)!!!  Interestingly, "Member" is not a valid option for Role, that is, the csv file can only contain a role for Owners.